# I am having this issue when I run npm i iconv. or npm install

Tags: node.js, npm

```sh
D:\KT_PHPAgency-client\Main_source_code\7Tablets-php-ow-67821c543913\server>npm install

> iconv@3.0.0 install D:\KT_PHPAgency-client\Main_source_code\7Tablets-php-ow-67821c543913\server\node_modules\iconv
> node-gyp rebuild


D:\KT_PHPAgency-client\Main_source_code\7Tablets-php-ow-67821c543913\server\node_modules\iconv>if not defined npm_config_node_gyp (node "C:\Users\vennila.p\AppData\Roaming\nvm\v12.16.3\node_modules\npm\node_modules\npm-lifecycle\node-gyp-bin\\..\..\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js" rebuild )  else (node "/usr/local/lib/node_modules/node-gyp/bin/node-gyp.js" rebuild )
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:960
  throw err;
  ^

Error: Cannot find module 'D:\usr\local\lib\node_modules\node-gyp\bin\node-gyp.js'
    at Function.Module._resolveFilename (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:957:15)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:840:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (internal/modules/run_main.js:74:12)
    at internal/main/run_main_module.js:18:47 {
  code: 'MODULE_NOT_FOUND',
  requireStack: []
}
npm WARN babel-loader@8.2.2 requires a peer of webpack@>=2 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@17.1.1 requires a peer of eslint@^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb@17.1.1 requires a peer of eslint-plugin-jsx-a11y@^6.2.3 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN eslint-config-airbnb-base@13.2.0 requires a peer of eslint@^4.19.1 || ^5.3.0 but none is installed. You must install peer dependencies yourself.
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@2.3.2 (node_modules\nodemon\node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@2.3.2: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})
npm WARN optional SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: fsevents@1.2.13 (node_modules\fsevents):
npm WARN notsup SKIPPING OPTIONAL DEPENDENCY: Unsupported platform for fsevents@1.2.13: wanted {"os":"darwin","arch":"any"} (current: {"os":"win32","arch":"x64"})

npm ERR! code ELIFECYCLE
npm ERR! errno 1
npm ERR! iconv@3.0.0 install: `node-gyp rebuild`
npm ERR! Exit status 1
npm ERR!
npm ERR! Failed at the iconv@3.0.0 install script.
npm ERR! This is probably not a problem with npm. There is likely additional logging output above.

npm ERR! A complete log of this run can be found in:
npm ERR!     C:\Users\vennila.p\AppData\Roaming\npm-cache\_logs\2021-04-12T05_04_44_564Z-debug.log
```

Comment: Have you tried reinstalling Node.js?

Comment: This comes in when there is a version issue. Try decreasing the version for `iconv@3.0.0`.

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara tried not working

Comment: Does this throw the same error?

Comment: @ApoorvaChikara yes

Comment: You can try this too -  upgrade the npm, install node-gyp. People solved these issues using these steps.